# Aws lambda not showing "Task timed out" error while connecting rds with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am getting a mysterious error of Tasked timing out as shown in the screenshot I attached
[image]

Here I tried to connect with my rds database with boto3 provided all the required params like secret keys arn etc but still, nothing seems to work.Connected with proper vpc's and given role to lambda with all required policies

here is the code on lamda

```
import json
import boto3

rds_data = boto3.client('rds-data')

database_name = ''
db_clust_arn = ''
db_secret_arn = ''

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    sql = """"
    response = rds_data.execute_statement(
    resourceArn = db_clust_arn, 
    secretArn = db_secret_arn, 
    database = database_name, 
    sql = sql,
    )
    print(str(response))

enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [RDS Lambda Proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-rds-proxy-with-aws-lambda/).

When you put your lambda in the VPC it won't have access to make HTTP calls by default so the request will never be routed to RDS, even though they are in the same VPC. That's because Lambda doesn't have an ENI attached which can route your requests.